# What is an odd Maass form

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, automorphic-forms

A Maass form for a congruence subgroup $\Gamma$ of $SL(2, \mathbb Z)$ is a complex valued smooth function $f$ on the upper half plane $\mathbb{H}$ such that

- $f$ is $\Gamma$-invariant
- $f$ is eigenvalue of the Laplacian
- $f$ is of at most polynomial vertical growth

These correspond to the *even* principal series $P_0$. I would like to know if we have a classical/explicit definition for the *odd* Maass forms (i.e. the functions corresponding to off principal series). I don't find much references on the topic.

Comment: Those are not even Maass forms; those are just Maass forms. Even Maass forms are those additionally satisfying $f(-\overline{z}) = f(z)$, while odd Maass forms satisfy $f(-\overline{z}) = -f(z)$. The former are spherical vectors for spherical principal series representations $|\cdot|^{it} \boxplus |\cdot|^{-it}$ of $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{R})$; the latter are vectors in the minimal $K$-type (which is the determinant representation of $\mathrm{O}(2)$) of the nonspherical principal series representation $\mathrm{sgn} |\cdot|^{it} \boxplus \mathrm{sgn} |\cdot|^{-it}$.